# Wildcard VS T - getting and adding to a list

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following program:

```
public class WCVsT {

    private void fooWC(List<? extends Number> l ) {
        l.add(l.get(0)); // 1 -  A Compile time error
    }

    private <T extends Number> void fooT(List<T> l) {
        l.add(l.get(0)); // 2 - No compile time error
    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions regarding it:

1. At 1 (in fooWC method) I am retrieving an element from the list and
       adding it back to the same list - what could be type unsafe about it? Why does the
       compiler not allow such operation? I can understand that the compiler doesn't allow adding a Cat to `List<? extends Animal>` because I could have passed dogs to fooWC but what my program shows now should always be safe. Isn't it?
2. Why the fooT method that uses
       Type parameter instead of wildcard allow such an operation whereas
       fooWC - the wildcard version doesn't?

Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason one works and the other doesn't is that while both methods use the bound `<T extends Number>`, in the second method (the typed method), the type although unknown, is the *same* type throughout the method - the type is locked to a particular (but unknown) type for the duration of the call.

In the first method (the untyped one), the compiler knows only that the list of unknown is having added to it an unknown type, which is possibly a *different* unknown type. The fact that it's obvious to humans that it must be the same type because the target and source are the same object are invisible to the compiler.

The first version is considered by the compiler to be in the same bucket as:

```
List<Integer> list1;
List<Double> list2;
list1.add(list2.get(0);
```

It just knows that the types are both bounded by `Number`, but not necessarily the *same* type.

The second version is in the same bucket as:

```
List<Integer> list1;
List<Integer> list2;
list1.add(list2.get(0);
```

The compiler doesn't know the type, but knows it's the *same* type.

Comment: +1 Though sometimes I feel that, few things could have been improved in Java generics. This is one of those. Compiler should have been made smart enough to identify that adding `l.get(0)` to `l` is safe. But, but..

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for your answer. When you say In the first method (the untyped one), the compiler knows only that the list of unknown is having added to it an unknown type, which is possibly a different unknown type. Can it really be a different unknown type or is that what the compiler thinks? If it really can be - please give an example.

Comment: @Mustafa in actuality it can't be a different type, and is safe, because the source and target lists are the same object. But the compiler doesn't know that. It knows only that an element of a list of unknown type is being added to a list of unknown type - it's not smart enough to notice that the two lists are the *same* list.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian ! I have moved on to Type Erasure now and reading from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html. It is so darn confusing ! I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @Mustafa Don't feel at all like you are unusual - it *is* confusing! IT takes everyone a while to become used to it. Get as much practice as you can with generics - it's worth it in the end